# How to combine pyspark dataframes with different shapes and different columns

Tags: pyspark

I have two dataframes in Pyspark. One has more than 1000 rows and the other only 4 rows. The columns also are not matching.

df1 with more than 1000 rows:

```
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+
| ID |  col1  |     col2     |     col 3   |
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | time1  | value_col2   |  value_col3 |
|  2 | time 2 |  value2_col2 | value2_col3 |
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+
...
```

df2 with only 4 rows:

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| key |     col_c    |     col_d    |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| a   |  valuea_colc | valuea_cold  |
| b   | valueb_colc  |  valueb_cold |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to create a dataframe looking like this:

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| ID |  col1  |     col2    |     col 3   |    a_col_c   |    a_col_d    |   b_col_c    |   b_col_d   |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | time1  | value_col2  |  value_col3 |  valuea_colc |   valuea_cold | valueb_colc  | valueb_cold |
|  2 | time 2 | value2_col2 | value2_col3 | valuea_colc  | valuea_cold   |  valueb_colc | valueb_cold |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Can you please help with this? I prefer not to use Pandas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out using crossJoin.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html explains how to use crossJoin with Pyspark DataFrames.